Luke 18:18-42: Why wouldn’t Jesus consider himself as "Good" like God the Father?
In Luke 18:18-42, we read:
9 “Why do you call me good?” Jesus answered. “No one is good—except God alone.
please, see this discussion on the meaning of Good: What is the meaning of "good" in Luke 18:19?
see also: “Why do you call Me good? No one is good except God alone. Why does Jesus rebuke the young man? (Mark 10:18)
Why wouldn’t Jesus consider himself as "Good" like God the Father? Could this passage be used as an argument against the theology of the Trinity?

If you look at the answers and discussion in the questions you linked, you'll see that this verse is used by some as an argument against the theology of the Trinity, while Trinitarians few the question as rhetorical rather than a denial by Jesus of His goodness. What's your question here that isn't answered in the questions you linked?

This question is similar to: In Luke 18:19 (and parallels), what does "good" (αγαθος) mean?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No. John 5:32 (NIV) — "There is another who testifies in my favor, and I know that his testimony about me is true"; John 5:37 (KJV) — "And the Father himself, which hath sent me, hath borne witness of me. Ye have neither heard his voice at any time, nor seen his shape"; John 5:41 (KJV) — "I receive not honour from men".

Answer
Jesus considered Himself as “Good” when He said, “I am the Good Shepherd” (John 10:11).
Explanation
Jesus Christ stated categorically that He is good when He said, “I am the Good Shepherd” (John 10:11).
Jesus is the Shepherd

“I am the Good Shepherd” (John 10:14).

Jehovah is the Shepherd
In the Old Testament, it is Yahweh who is the Shepherd:

“the Mighty One of Jacob, from the Shepherd, the Rock of Israel. From
the God of your father” (Gen 49:24-25).


“Give ear, O Shepherd of Israel, You leading Joseph like a flock;
shine forth, You dwelling between the cherubs” (Psalms 80:1).


“Jehovah is my Shepherd” (Psalms 23:1).

Jehovah is Good

“Taste and see that Jehovah is good” (Psalms 34:8).

Jesus is Good

“if indeed you "tasted" "that the Lord (Jesus) is good” (1 Pet
2:3).

Conclusion
Jehovah God is good. Jesus the Lord is good.

This argumentation is extremely weak. Gen 4:2: ויהי־הבל רעה - Abel is a shepherd. Abel is good.

I once asked a man who knew N.T. Greek whether Jesus used the same word for 'good' in John 10:14 as the word appearing in Luke 18. He paused for thought then answered, "No, there are differences in those two words translated 'good'." But as this was about 2 decades ago, I cannot remember the details. As it is Greek language that has a bearing in this question, can you clarify that please?

@AviAvraham - I am not arguing anything here. The OP asked why Jesus would not consider Himself as good. I answered saying Jesus did consider Himself as good, twice. Besides, the Scripture does not say that Abel is the good shepherd.

@Anne - Yes, 2 different Greek words are used by Jesus; in Luke 18:19, He used “G18:agathos” and in John 10:14, “G2570:kalos”. Agathos is something that is intrinsically good. Kalos is not only intrinsically good but attractive externally also. These are used interchangeably in Greek. See: “and having a reputation for good (kalos) works: if she has brought up children, has shown hospitality, has washed the feet of the saints, has cared for the afflicted, and has devoted herself to every good (agathos) work” (1 Tim 5:10).

Here is a beautiful article on these two words. I am sure you will like it: https://www.christiancentury.org/article/editorpublisher/when-goodness-also-lovely#:~:text=Agathos%20defines%20the%20quality%20of,an%20attractive%20or%20captivating%20character.

Appreciate your response, and will now have a look at that link.

You are most welcome, Anne.

In the first place, Jesus didn't say he wasn't good. He asked why the man was calling him good, without actually contradicting what he said. In the second place, it was a lesson on humility. As Paul says, all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God. And as John says, if we say we have no sin, we deceive ourselves, and the truth is not in us. Only God is good. The rest of us fall short.
If Jesus, perceived as a mortal man, is being called good when all are sinners, then the man is being admonished for calling him good when there is none good but God. But Jesus still didn't deny being good.

Sorry, but you don't understand the context of that story.  Jesus' comment about the goodness of God has two objectives.
The first is to expose rich young ruler's self-righteousness. The man asks about the everlasting life. Christ tells him that only God is good and advices him to keep the commandments. For which the guy says, I have kept them all since my youth. In other words, he told Jesus that he himself is good. No one except the Messiah kept the law perfectly, but there we have a man who claims that keeping it is a piece of cake. Have you ever read Psalm 14 young ruler?

1 The fool a says in his heart, “There is no God.” They are corrupt,
their deeds are vile; there is no one who does good. 2 The Lord looks
down from heaven on all mankind to see if there are any who
understand, any who seek God. 3 All have turned away, all have become
corrupt; there is no one who does good, not even one. 4 Do all these
evildoers know nothing? They devour my people as though eating bread;
they never call on the Lord. 5 But there they are, overwhelmed with
dread, for God is present in the company of the righteous. 6 You
evildoers frustrate the plans of the poor, but the Lord is their
refuge. 7 Oh, that salvation for Israel would come out of Zion! When
the Lord restores his people, let Jacob rejoice and Israel be glad!

Your own scriptures testify that you are delusional, young man.
Secondly, Jesus hints here that He Himself is God. If only God is good, and you, young ruler, called me good, what does that make Me?
Psalm 117 in Septuagint (118 in the MT), for example, calls God good (agathos) five times. In the Hebrew version, it contains the word salvation (יְשׁוּעָה), which is Jesus' name, three times.

1 [Alleluia.] Give thanks to the Lord; for [he is] good: for his mercy
[endures] for ever.  2 Let now the house of Israel say, that [he is]
good: for his mercy [endures] for ever.  3 Let now the house of Aaron
say, that [he is] good: for his mercy [endures] for ever.  4 Let now
all that fear the Lord say, that [he is] good: for his mercy [endures]
for ever.  5 I called on the Lord out of affliction: and he hearkened
to me, [so as to bring me] into a wide place.  6 The Lord is my
helper; and I will not fear what man shall do to me.  7 The Lord is my
helper; and I shall see [my desire] upon mine enemies.  8 [It is]
better to trust in the Lord than to trust in man.  9 [It is] better to
hope in the Lord, than to hope in princes.  10 All nations compassed
me about: but in the name of the Lord I repulsed them.  11 They
completely compassed me about: but in the name of the Lord I repulsed
them.  12 They compassed me about as bees [do] a honeycomb, and they
burst into flame as fire among thorns: but in the name of the Lord I
repulsed them. 13 I was thrust, and sorely shaken, that I might fall:
but the Lord helped me.  14 The Lord is my strength and my song, and
is become my salvation.  15 The voice of exultation and salvation is
in the tabernacles of the righteous: the right hand of the Lord has
wrought mightily.  16 The right hand of the Lord has exalted me: the
right hand of the Lord has wrought powerfully.  17 I shall not die,
but live, and recount the works of the Lord.  18 The Lord has
chastened me sore: but he has not given me up to death.  19 Open to me
the gates of righteousness: I will go into them, and give praise to
the Lord.  20 This is the gate of the Lord: the righteous shall enter
by it.  21 I will give thanks to thee; because thou hast heard me, and
art become my salvation.  22 The stone which the builders rejected,
the same is become the head of the corner.  23 This has been done of
the Lord; and it is wonderful in our eyes.  24 This is the day which
the Lord has made: let us exult and rejoice in it.  25 O Lord, save
now: O Lord, send now prosperity.  26 Blessed is he that comes in the
name of the Lord: we have blessed you out of the house of the Lord.
27 God is the Lord, and he has shined upon us: celebrate the feast
with thick [branches, binding the victims] even to the horns of the
altar.  28 Thou art my God, and I will give thee thanks: thou art my
God, and I will exalt thee. I will give thanks to thee, for thou hast
heard me, and art become my salvation.  29 Give thanks to the Lord;
for he is good: for his mercy [endures] for ever.


There are different levels of goodness shown in the Scriptures.  The highest level of goodness is God, who is completely and absolutely good.  The meaning of "God" in this verse, from the Greek dictionary, is "the supreme Divinity."   The Kingdom of God is a hierarchy.  Even though Jesus considered himself the Son of God (John 5), and the good shepherd (John 10:11), he said in John 10:14, "...for my Father is greater than I."
